# Update parameters of Bayesian Network with new data

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

I have a bayesian network, and I know the CPTs by learning the probabilities from existing data.
Suppose I receive a new data instance. Ideally I don't want to use all the data again to update the probabilities.

Is there a way to incrementally update the CPTs of the existing network each time new data comes in?
I think there should be, and I feel like I'm missing something :)

Comment: Can you provide sample codes that produce CPT from data? I want to create a BN from data and then obtain CPT from data. Then use this network to query about  new coming data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to maintain the joint probability table, and rebuild the CPT from that as needed. Along with the JPT, keep a count of how many examples were used to produce it. When adding the `n`th example, multiply all probabilities by `1 - 1/n`, and then add probability `1/n` to the new example's associated probability.

If you're going to do this a bunch, you should maintain a count of examples for each row in the JPT instead of a probability. That'll cut down on numerical drift.